# C# - Process.Start() does not launch ClickOnce application on Windows Server 2019 - worked fine on 2008 R2

Tags: c#, clickonce, system-administration, windows-server-2019

I have a C# application that is published via ClickOnce to a network drive. I have another process that I use to launch this application via the code below that points to the ClickOnce shortcut:

```
string path = "Z:\\MyApp\\MyApp.application";
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
process.Start();
```

This code has worked forever on Server 2008 R2 without any issues. As soon as I upgraded to Server 2019, it is no longer consistently reliable. There are no errors thrown. Nothing happens when I try it...

unless I launch **any** ClickOnce application right before this from the same mapped drive. Right after, `Process.Start()` will suddenly start working for all applications I want to launch until it eventually fails again a few hours later. The drive mapping is not being lost during this time. My guess is it is a security issue, but this system as well as previous ones have all been running under the local Administrator account. Neither is on any domain.

This only impacts ClickOnce `.application` links. Any direct `.exe` files I try to launch from the same network drive work just fine.

Comment: Anything showing up in the event logs? You could try Process Monitor to try to get additional error/problem information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Do you execute the launcher as Administrator?

Comment: I would also specify the working folder when starting the process:  `processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToMyExe);`

Comment: I am a local administrator already. Are there any security policy settings I should tweak?

I will set the `WorkingDirectory` and give it a shot.

Comment: This sounds like a sensible security policy - ClickOnce is a way to deploy applications to *end users*, not tools that are called by other processes without the end user's consent. A ClickOnce has to connect to a server and download the latest version each time it runs, something that shouldn't be done without the end user knowing about it.  Why are you using a ClickOnce to begin with, instead of deploying the application in any other way?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing *without* an administrator account? The restriction may apply to administrator accounts only, like many other restrictions. An app running as an admin can wreak havoc to the entire machine. You shouldn't be using an admin account to run tools automatically anyway.

Comment: `worked forever on Server 2008 R2` this doesn't mean much. This is a 10 year-old version that reached End Of Life several years ago. Security settings have changed *a lot* since then. The setting that blocks you could go as far back as 2012.

Comment: The issue is it works fine for a period of time after I launch any ClickOnce application manually. It just seems to fall asleep again after a few hours.